# How first letters of each word in a string phrase can be converted to uppercase?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

I search for the possible methods that firstly splits the phrase into words and collect in an array. And I can do the converting stuff of first letters of each word. However, my function is not working and takes too long.

Here's my implementation.

`public String toUpCase(String phrase)
    {
String[] words = phrase.split("");
        String output = "";

        for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            while(i != words.length-1){
                output  += Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)) + words[i].substring(1) + " ";
            }

            output += Character.toUpperCase(words[words.length-1].charAt(0)) + words[words.length-1].substring(1);
        }

        return output;`

}

Is there any other solution so that I can split my phrase properly?
Thanks.

Comment: `split(" ");`........

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried this but my compiler does not return the result and makes CPU overrun.

Comment: You shoudn't have a while loop inside your for loop. Especially not an infinite one. All you need to do inside the loop is capitalizes the first letter of the word, and add the result to the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not splitting the word with space delimiter and also the logic inside the loop is incorrect, you need to follow the below steps:

(1) Split the phrase with space i.e., words array

(2) Iterate each word

(3) Capitalize the first character using `Character.toUpperCase`

(4) Get the remaining word i.e., from index 1

(5) Suffix space for each word

You can refer the below code with inline comments:

```
public static String toUpCase(String phrase) {
        //split the phrase with space
        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");

        //Use StringBuilder to append the strings
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        //loop the words array
        for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String temp = words[i];
            output.append(Character.
               toUpperCase(temp.charAt(0))).//convert the first char to uppercase
                append(temp.substring(1)).//get the string from index 1
                append(" ");//append space for each word
        }
        return output.toString();//convert stringbuilder to string 
    }
```

> I couldn't get the idea behind using a space after the last word?

Because we have split the phrase with space, the elements of the `words` array will not contain space in them, so we simply need to add the space for each word again.

---

Also, **always use `StringBuilder` when performing with string operations**, especially inside the loops.

Comment: This is very useful info but I couldn't get the idea behind using a space after the last word?

Comment: you have split the array with space right, so you have lost the space i.e., array elements does not have space in them, so you need to add the space again for each word, clear?

Comment: Updated my answer with your question, you can accept my answer if it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use [org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils.capitalize](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class something {
    String toUpCase(String phrase) {
        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (String word : words) {
            output.append(Character.toUpperCase(word.charAt(0)))
            .append(word.substring(1))
            .append(" ");
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll never figure out how to format these answers x.x But does that code work for your purpose? If not why not?

Comment: Yes, but when it is on the last element of the array which is the last word of the phrase, it puts a space after the last word. So, how can I prevent this case?

Comment: Well if you do the for loop that JavaGuy uses you could put an if statement before the append(" ") that makes it skip it if it's the last iteration of the loop.